# htaccess redirect regex doesn't work

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I have some text:

```
/page2/
/page265/
/page23/
/page7657658587/
```

How do I match them? I copy this code in .htaccess file to redirect to a php file  but it doesn't work.

```
RewriteRule \/page.*\/ t.php [L]
```

Comment: You should change your title. This is not "PHP regex", rather "PERL regex", which Apache uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^page(\d+)/?$ t.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Rule in a perDir context (including `.htaccess` rules should not include the leading `/` so something like `^page(\d+)/?$` would be better.